# Excel VBA - Chart Referencing Not Working

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to update a max scale and minimum scale for the chart in different sheet (Sheet2) with values from Sheet1. However i'm getting Object required error. Below is the code:

```
Sub ChangeAxisScale()
Dim wsChart As Chart
Dim wsInput As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long


Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With Sheet2.ChartObjects("Chart").Chart.Axes(xlValue)
        LastRow = wsInput.Cells(wsInput.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        .MaximumScale = wsInput.Cells(LastRow, 4).Value
        .MinimumScale = wsInput.Range("D2").Value
End With
End Sub
```

The line that error appeared is `With Sheet2.ChartObjects("Chart").Chart.Axes(xlValue)`. Did i referencing the chart wrongly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs fine if the chart is on a sheet whose **internal** name is "Sheet2". If the chart is on a differently named sheet, the code will fail.

You may want to use a Dim statement to declare and properly set the sheet that the chart is on.

```
Sub ChangeAxisScale()
Dim wsChart As Chart ' you don't really need that, right?
Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsChartSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long


Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsChartSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With wsChartSheet.ChartObjects("Chart").Chart.Axes(xlValue)
        LastRow = wsInput.Cells(wsInput.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        .MaximumScale = wsInput.Cells(LastRow, 4).Value
        .MinimumScale = wsInput.Range("D2").Value
End With
End Sub
```